# Coca leaves - legal status in Spain

Tags: legal, spain, south-america, drugs

A man who imported 2kg of coca leaf powder was freed from the accused charge of drug trafficking by a court in Spain: 
https://www.tni.org/en/article/absolution-in-a-judicial-case-of-coca-leaf-in-spain

https://idpc.net/alerts/2017/03/acquittal-in-spanish-coca-leaf-legal-case

http://www.elmundo.es/cataluna/2017/03/15/58c97970e5fdea012e8b45dc.html

I am still trying to figure out two things: is this ruling now official and does that mean I can take small quantities of coca leaves back to Spain from my holiday?

Comment: Note that the link is to a campaigning group not an independent news gathering site.

Comment: I added a link to an elmundo article

Comment: I think this would be better on [law.se]. It's purely a question about Spanish law and the travel part is only incidental.

Comment: Good point, I will as it there

Comment: Note that this ruling can still be overruled by higher courts. In general it is forbidden to possess any psicoactive substances -- that's why weed seeds are legal but weed itself is not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was moved to Law.